# Is it possible to make my list of saved questions accessible during "duplicate close" dialogue?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-dialog, saves

It would be great to have access to ones saved questions in the "duplicate close" flow. Most of my saves are duplicate targets for questions that keep on getting asked somewhat frequently (I even named the folder where they are saved "duplicate targets").

Right now, if I vote to close a question as a duplicate of the ones I have saved, I have to either open another tab, access my saves, copy the link and paste it back to the first tab as the duplicate of choice or I have to have the title of the question memorized well enough to be able to quickly find it via the search function (which is not all that trivial because many questions have similar titles).

I know this is only a minor inconvenience, but it would really make things go more smoothly if when voting to close a question as a duplicate, there is a button to access my saved questions.

Answer (score 15):

That is indeed a nice idea, and would be helpful.

This is how I see it done, in my vision:

[image: sketch of the request, drop down list with the saves list]

Drop down list will be added, and when selecting a Saves list there, the questions in the list will replace the suggestions.

Comment: Exactly! That is how I would imagine that.