How to easily access your "saved for later"/duplicates list when voting duplicates
It would be very useful, when voting on a question as duplicate, if one could easily access the "Saved for later" list (or whatever list one uses), since that's where I keep the commonly duplicated questions and their answers.
Right now one has to open another window, browse to the user page, click on saved for later, copy the link, which takes forever.
Or does someone have a good workflow for this issue? Probably 50% of questions on the tags I'm interested in are duplicates, but Stack Overflow doesn't make it easier to vote them down.
The searching for the duplicates in the Vote window is unfortunately not good enough, and doesn't prioritize questions saved for later as far as I know.

for the FR part of the question, duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396785/is-it-possible-to-make-my-list-of-saved-questions-accessible-during-duplicate-c

Given the "Saves" feature isn't supported by the Stack API creating a userscript to bring saves to the close dialog will be an undertaking riddled with maintenance nightmares due to SEs habbit to change page structures over night. That said: I couldn't find a userscript request: https://stackapps.com/search?tab=newest&q=saves&searchOn=3  and I know more users are interested in this.

One thing to make the workflow easier,  at least for one step less, is to keep the saved list page open in your browser tabs (mine expands to 4 / 50 page splits though )

Re "Right now one has to open another window, browse to the user page, click on saved for later, copy the link, which takes forever.": The first part can be handled by a (web browser) bookmark for this URL ("current" for the current user's ID). It can be made shorter by a macro on your macro keyboard (or the equivalent, for example, some host-side solution), also automating the opening of a new tab.

The saves are also in the left side bar, a simple middle click opens a new tab with the saves: proof


The searching for the duplicates in the Vote window is unfortunately not good enough

Simply add in:saves to your search query, and the results will automatically be restricted to questions in your saves. This does not, as far as I know, allow for selecting a specific saves list, but I have found it immensely helpful in closing duplicates.

That's a good suggestion, but it seems do some some kind of intelligent (and i use the term loosely) search so not all items in in:saves are displayed!

@siggemannen It's limited to showing 30 (might be user-configurable) results; and it can only find questions, not answers. But otherwise, I have consistently found that when the results don't turn up like I expect, it's either because the question doesn't contain keywords I thought it did (or the stemming works weirdly), or because I typo'd something, e.g. in;saves or in:svaes.
